# Correct (lore-based) order of the Halo games

Tags: halo-series

I own the following Halo games:

- Halo: The Master Chief Collection (Halo 1-4)
- Halo: Reach
- Halo: ODST
- Halo Wars

Since some games are actually prequels and I'm not sure in what order I have to play them to "understand" the lore I'd like to know in what order I have to play them to actually follow the story correctly (So I'd like a list based on the lore, not the release dates).

Comment: -1 for reminding me Halo Wars was a thing (jk)

Comment: I didn't like it too much either :D

Comment: I rather enjoyed it. Definitely shallow and nothing special, but it was fun all the same

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The canonical chronological order for the Halo franchise is:

1. Halo Wars
2. Halo: Reach
3. Halo: Combat Evolved
4. Halo 2
5. Halo: Spartan Strike (overlaps with Halo 2)
6. Halo 3: ODST (also overlaps with Halo 2, but serves primarily as a prequel leading to Halo 3).
7. Halo 3
8. Halo: Spartan Assault
9. Halo 4
10. Halo 5
11. Halo Wars 2

Comment: ODST also overlaps with the events of Halo 2.

Comment: @cbirdsong thank you! I did not know that. I knew it happened after Halo 2 and before 3, but not that it occurred at the same time.

Comment: ODST starts in the middle of two when (spoilers for those who haven't played the game) the Covvie ship jumps away from New Mombasa and the Forward Unto Dawn follows it. The ODSTs jump into that city as the ships jump and deal with the invasion and occupation. The story continues overnight and ends the next day with the Covvies glassing the city. This glassing occurs a third of the way through Halo 3 in response to the flood landing on Earth.

Comment: Halo Wars 2 should be added to this list.

Comment: Don’t forget to add halo infinite last ;). At least I’m assuming it based on halo 5 ending with Cortana going mad.