# Halo Franchise In A Chronological Order

Tags: halo-series

I want to know everything about the Halo series, covering everything from books, comics, games, animation.

So far I got the list only for the games.

I would be really satisfied if I get the list.

Comment: [Related (chronological order of games)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191009/correct-lore-based-order-of-the-halo-games)

Comment: You want to know everything? That's a lot.

Answer (score 3):

An entire timeline of canonical fiction can be found on the Halo Wikia:

http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canonical_fiction

replicated below, please see the link for working links to more info on these articles.

```
Timeline of Halo media
Year Title Author/Studio 
107,000 BCE Halo 4 Terminal 1 - War The Sequence Group
107,000 BCE Halo 4 Terminal 2 - Lord of Admirals    The Sequence Group
106,000 BCE Halo 4 Terminal 3 - Charum Hakkor   The Sequence Group
106,000 BCE Halo 4 Terminal 4 - Flood   The Sequence Group
97,700 BCE  Soma the Painter    
97,446 BCE  Halo: Cryptum   Greg Bear
97,446 BCE  Halo: Primordium    Greg Bear
97,446 BCE  Halo: Silentium Greg Bear
97,446 BCE  Halo 4 Terminal 5 - Knights The Sequence Group
97,446 BCE  Halo 4 Terminal 6 - Justice The Sequence Group
97,446 BCE  Halo 4 Terminal 7 - Cryptum The Sequence Group
97,446 BCE  The Cradle of Life  
97,446 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 2 - Halo The Sequence Group
97,446 BCE  Halo: Rebirth   Greg Bear & Erik Bear
97,446 BCE  Promises to Keep    
40,000 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 4 - The Silent Cartographer  The Sequence Group
40,000 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 5 - Assault on the Control Room  The Sequence Group
40,000 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 6 - 343 Guilty Spark The Sequence Group
40,000 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 7 - The Library  The Sequence Group
40,000 BCE  Halo: CEA Terminal 8 - Two Betrayals    The Sequence Group
860 BCE (Prologue)
851-850 BCE (Part 1)
2552 CE (Part 2)    Halo: Broken Circle John Shirley
2142 CE The Duel    Production I.G.
2310 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 1   
2362 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 2   
2381 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 3   
2415 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 4   
2491 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 5   
2491 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 6   
2508 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 7   
2513-2517 CE (issue 1)
2517-2525 CE (issue 2)
2525 CE (issues 3-4)    Halo: Fall of Reach - Boot Camp Brian Reed
2517 CE (Section 1)
2517-2525 CE (Section 2)
2552 CE (Sections 3-6)  Halo: The Fall of Reach Eric Nylund
2517-2519 CE (Act 1)
2525 CE (Act 2-3)   Halo: The Fall of Reach - The Animated Series   The Sequence Group & 343 Industries
2517-2528 CE    Pariah  B. K. Evenson
2524-2525 CE    Halo: Contact Harvest   Joseph Staten
2525 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 8   
2525 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 9   
2525 CE (issue 1)
2525-2552 CE (issue 2)
2552 CE (issue 3-4) Halo: Fall of Reach - Covenant  Brian Reed
2525-2531 CE    Halo Wars: Genesis  Eric Nylund
2525 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 10  
2525 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 11  
2525 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 12  
2526 CE Halo 4: Forward Unto Dawn   
2528 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 13  
2530 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 14  
2530 CE I kissed a boy once.    
2530 CE Spirit of Bloody Fire. Cutter. Bloody hell. 
2531 CE I have a bridge to look after here. 
2531 CE Privilege   
2531 CE The Day Before  
2531 CE Sit down and strap in.  
2531 CE Homecoming  Production I.G., Bee Train
2531 CE Attacks 
2531 CE Halo Wars   Ensemble Studios
2531 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 15  
2531 CE (Section 1)
2531-2551 CE (Section 2)
2552 CE (Section 3-Epilogue)    Halo: Ghosts of Onyx    Eric Nylund
2532 CE Prototype   Bones
2532 CE Midnight in the Heart of Midlothian Frank O'Connor
2533 CE Birth of a Spartan  
2535 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 16  
2535 CE Halo: The Cole Protocol Tobias Buckell
2542 CE The Babysitter  Studio 4˚C
2544 CE The Package Casio Entertainment
2535 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 17  
2550 CE Cortana and Solipsil    
2551 CE Headhunters Jonathan Goff
2551 CE
2558 CE Halo: Escalation - The Glass Horizon    Duffy Boudreau
2551-2552 CE    Halo 2: Anniversary Terminal 14 - Beholden  The Sequence Group
2552 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 18  
2552 CE Halo Reach Data Pad 19  
2552 CE (January)   Halo: Helljumper    Peter David
2552 CE (April) Deliver Hope    
2552 (July) CE  Blunt Instruments   Fred Van Lente
2552 (July) CE  Halo: Blood Line    Fred Van Lente
2552 (July) CE  Halo: Reach Bungie
2552 (August) CE    Unggoy Conversation 
2552 (August) CE (Section 0 & 2)
2552 (September) CE (Section 1 & 3-7)   Halo: First Strike  
2552 (September) CE Dirt    Tobias Buckell
2552 (September) CE Black Box from Sacred Promise   
2552 (September) CE 343 Guilty Spark's Log  
2552 (September) CE The Flood   William Dietz
2552 (September) CE Halo: Combat Evolved    Bungie
2552 (September) CE Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary    Bungie, Saber Interactive
2552 (September) CE Halo: CEA Terminal 1 - The Pillar of Autumn The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: CEA Terminal 3 - The Truth and Reconciliation The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Breaking Quarantine Tsutomu Nihei
2552 (September) CE The Last Voyage of the Infinite Succor  Lee Hammock
2552 (September) CE Halo: CEA Terminal 9 - Keyes    The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: CEA Terminal 10 - The Maw The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: CEA Terminal 11 - Threshold   The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 4 - Monitor Report: Heresy Indeed The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 5 - Monitor Report: Containment   The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 7 - Monitor Report: Unequal Union The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 9 - Monitor Report: Divine Inspiration    The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 11 - Monitor Report: Age of Doubt The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 13 - Monitor Report: False Journey    The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 1 - ONI File: Target Profile  The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 2 - ONI File: Honor Bound The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Halo: 2A Terminal 3 - ONI File: Particular Justice  The Sequence Group
2552 (September) CE Letter from Supposition 
2552 (September) CE Sangheili Conversation  
2552 (October) CE   Letter from Truth   
2552 (October) CE   Armor Testing   Ed Lee, Jay Faerber, and Andrew Robinson
2552 (October) CE   Letter to the Master Chief  
2552 (October) CE   Halo: 2A Terminal 15 - Unyielding   The Sequence Group
2552 (October–November) CE  Halo 2  Bungie
2552 (October–November) CE  Halo 2: Anniversary Bungie, Saber Interactive
2552 (October) CE   Another Day at the Beach    Bungie
2552 (October) CE   Palace Hotel    Robert McLees
2552 (October) CE   Second Sunrise Over New Mombasa Brett Lewis
2552 (October) CE   Sadie's Story   
2552 (October) CE   Halo 3: ODST    Bungie
2552 (October) CE   The Mona Lisa   Tessa Kum and Jeff VanderMeer
2552 (November) CE  Halo: 2A Terminal 6 - Covenant Record: Will of the Prophets The Sequence Group
2552 (November) CE  Halo: 2A Terminal 8 - Covenant Record: Taming the Hunters   The Sequence Group
2552 (November) CE  Halo: 2A Terminal 10 - Covenant Record: Unggoy Rebellion    The Sequence Group
2552 (November) CE  Halo: 2A Terminal 12 - Covenant Record: The Great Schism    The Sequence Group
2552 (November) CE  Wages of Sin    
2552 (November) CE  Halo: Uprising  Brian Michael Bendis
2552 (November) CE  Human Weakness  Karen Traviss
2552 (November) CE  Halo: Landfall  
2552 (November–December) CE Halo 3  Bungie
2552 (December) CE  Living Moment   
2552 (December) CE  The Impossible Life and the Possible Death of Preston J. Cole   Eric Nylund
2553 CE Halo: Glasslands    Karen Traviss
2553 CE Halo: Initiation    Brian Reed
2553 CE From the Office of Dr. William Arthur Iqbal 
2553 CE Shadow of Intent    Joseph Staten
2553 CE Breaking Strain 
2553 CE Halo: The Thursday War  Karen Traviss
2553 CE Halo: Mortal Dictata    Karen Traviss
2553 CE Halo: Last Light    Troy Denning
2553 CE A Necessary Truth   
2553 CE Petra   
2554 CE
2557 CE Halo 4 Prologue - Location Unknown  The Sequence Group
2554 CE (March) Lessons Learned 
2555 CE Halo Online Saber Interactive
2555 CE Halo: Hunters in the Dark   Peter David
2555 CE Halo: New Blood Matt Forback
2556 CE Halo: Nightfall 
2556 CE Origins Studio 4˚C
2556 CE (March) Anarosa 
2557 CE (January)   Halo: Smoke and Shadow (Into the Fire)  Kelly Gay
2557 CE (July)  Halo 4  343 Industries
2557 CE Halo: Escalation -The Next 72 Hours Brian Reed
2557 CE Halo: Spartan Assault   Vanguard Games
2557 CE Halo: Spartan Strike    Vanguard Games
2558 CE (January)   Halo: Saint's Testimony Frank O'Connor
2558 CE Spartan Ops 343 Industries
2558 CE Halo: Escalation (issues 1-6)   Christopher Schlerf
2558 CE Halo: Escalation (issue 7)  Brian Reed
2558 CE Hunt the Truth Season 1 
2558 CE Halo: Escalation - Exposure Duffy Boudreau
2558 CE Halo: Escalation - The Janus Key    Duffy Boudreau
2558 CE Halo: Escalation - The Absolute Record  Duffy Boudreau
2558 CE (July)  Oasis   
2558 CE Hunt the Truth Season 2 
2558 CE (October)   Halo 5: Guardians   343 Industries
2558 CE (October)   What Remains    
2558 CE (October)   Rossbach's World    
2559 CE Halo Wars 2 Creative Assembly
2559 CE The Return  Kevin Grace
2610 CE Believe
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/235281)

Comment: @Riley Done. Now please retract your downvote. I hope you understand that right now, I don't have the time to manually go through this list and restore the hyperlinks one by one.

Comment: It's not my downvote so I cannot retract it unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Because it is quiet a list to post as an answer I will provide you with the [link](https://www.alltimelines.com/halo/).

> This list of Halo media includes:
>
> The Halo Games: Considered the “core” medium for the Halo franchise.
>   These include the main series of games, as well as a few mobile games
>   such as Spartan Assault.
>
> Novels/Comics: Halo has more tie-in novels and comics than any other video game franchise. I include them in the timeline.
>
> Films/Short Films: Though the Halo franchise has never seen a
>   theatrical release, the series does include a few films that were
>   released through other mediums, often online.

There are a few other pieces of media that fit in, such as the Hunt the Truth podcast, and you can find it all in chronological order below. We hope you enjoy!

as requested per review:

Series

> Halo Evolutions    Soma the Painter       2009-11-24
>
> Forerunner Saga      Cryptum  2011-01-04
>
> Forerunner Saga   Primordium      2012-01-03
>
> Forerunner Saga   Silentium       2013-03-19
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Defender of the Storm    2016-09-20
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Promises to Keep     2016-09-20
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Untitled Story   Short Story N/A 2016-09-20
>
> Broken Circle Novel   John Shirley    2014-11-04
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: The Duel   Short Film  John Powell 2010-02-16
>
> The Fall of Reach The Fall of Reach: Boot Camp    Graphic
>   Novel Brian Reed  2011-04-27
>
> Contact Harvest   Novel   Joseph Staten   2007-10-30
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Pariah  Short Story B. K.
>   Evenson   2009-11-24
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: Homecoming Short Film  John
>   Powell    2010-02-16
>
> Halo Wars Halo Wars: Genesis  Graphic Novel   Ensemble
>   Studios   2009-03-03
>
> Halo Wars Halo Wars   Game    Ensemble Studios    2009-02-26
>
> The Fall of Reach The Fall of Reach: Covenant Graphic Novel   Brian
>   Reed  2011-12-14
>
> The Fall of Reach The Fall of Reach   Short Film  Heath
>   Corson    2015-10-27
>
> Halo 4: Forward Unto Dawn Television  Aaron Helbing, Todd
>   Helbing   2012-11-02
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: The Ballad of Hamish Beamish Short
>   Story Frank O'Connor  2016-09-20
>
> The Cole Protocol Novel   Tobias S. Buckell   2008-11-25
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: Something Has
>   Happened  Comic Issue Alex Irvine 2016-10-25
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: The Package    Short Film  John
>   Powell    2010-02-16
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: Prototype  Short Film  John
>   Powell    2010-02-16
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Midnight in the Heart of
>   Midlothian    Short Story Frank O'Connor  2009-11-24
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: The Babysitter Short Film  John
>   Powell    2010-02-16
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Headhunters Short Story Jonathan
>   Goff  2009-11-24
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: Hunting Party Comic
>   Issue Jonathan Goff   2016-10-25
>
> Helljumpers   Graphic Novel   Peter David 2010-03-10
>
> Blood Line    Graphic Novel   Fred Van Lente  2010-07-28
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Blunt Instruments   Short Story Fred
>   Van Lente 2009-11-24
>
> The Fall of Reach The Fall of Reach   Novel   Eric Nylund 2001-10-30
>
> The Fall of Reach The Fall of Reach: Invasion Graphic Novel   Brian
>   Reed  2012-07-18
>
> Halo: Reach   Game    Bungie  2010-09-14
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Dirt    Short Story Tobias
>   Buckell   2009-11-24
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Stomping on the Heels of a Fuss Short
>   Story Eric Raab   2009-11-24
>
> The Original Halo Trilogy  Halo: Combat
>   Evolved   Game    Bungie  2001-11-15
>
> The Flood  Novel   William C. Dietz    2003-04-01
>
> Halo Graphic Novel    Halo Graphic Novel: Breaking Quarantine Comic
>   Issue Tsutomu Nihei   2006-07-19
>
> Halo Graphic Novel    Halo Graphic Novel: The Last Voyage of the
>   Infinite Succor   Comic Issue Lee Hammock 2006-07-19
>
> First Strike  Novel   Eric Nylund 2003-12-02
>
> Halo Graphic Novel    Halo Graphic Novel: Armor Testing   Comic
>   Issue Andrew Robinson, Ed Lee, Jay Faerber    2006-07-19
>
> Halo Evolutions    Evolutions: Mona Lisa  Short Story Jeff
>   VanderMeer, Tessa Kum 2009-11-24
>
> The Original Halo Trilogy Halo 2  Game    Bungie  2004-11-09
>
> Halo Graphic Novel    Halo Graphic Novel- Second Sunrise Over New
>   Mombasa   Comic Issue Jean Giraud 2006-07-19
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Palace Hotel    Short Story Robert
>   McLees    2009-11-24
>
> Ghosts of Onyx Novel   Eric Nylund 2006-10-31
>
> Uprising   Graphic Novel   Brian Michael Bendis    2009-06-17
>
> Landfall   Short Film  Neill Blomkamp  2007-07-10
>
> Halo 3: ODST  Game    Bungie  2009-09-22
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: Human Weakness  Short Story Karen
>   Traviss   2009-11-24
>
> The Original Halo Trilogy Halo 3  Game    Bungie  2007-09-25
>
> Halo Evolutions  Evolutions: Wages of Sin Short
>   Story N/A 2009-11-24
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: The Impossible Life & The Possible
>   Death of Preston Cole Short Story Eric Nylund 2009-11-24
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: From the Office of Dr. William Arthur
>   Iqbal Short Story Frank O'Connor  2009-11-24
>
> Kilo-Five Trilogy Glasslands  Novel   Karen Traviss   2011-10-25
>
> Shadow of Intent  Short Story Joseph Staten   2015-12-07
>
> Initiation    Graphic Novel   Brian Reed  2014-01-21
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Breaking Strain  Short Story James
>   Swallow   2016-09-20
>
> Kilo-Five Trilogy The Thursday War    Novel   Karen Traviss   2012-10-02
>
> Kilo-Five Trilogy Mortal Dictata  Novel   Karen Traviss   2014-01-21
>
> Last Light    Novel   Troy Denning    2015-09-15
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: A Necessary Truth    Short Story Troy
>   Denning   2016-09-20
>
> Retribution    Novel   Troy Denning    2017-08-29
>
> Hunters in the Dark    Novel   Peter David 2015-06-16
>
> New Blood  Novel   Matt Forbeck    2015-03-02
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Lessons Learned  Short Story Matt
>   Forbeck   2016-09-20          Legacy of Onyx  Novel   Matt Forbeck    2017-11-14
>
> Bad Blood Novel   Matt Forbeck    2018-04-24
>
> Halo: Spartan Assault Game    343 Industries  2013-07-18
>
> Halo: Nightfall   Television  Paul T. Scheuring   2015-03-16
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Anarosa  Short Story Kevin
>   Grace 2016-09-20
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Into the Fire   Short Story  Kelly
>   Gay   2016-09-20
>
> Smoke and Shadow  Novel   Kelly Gay   2016-11-28
>
> Halo: Legends Legends: Origins    Short Film  John Powell 2010-02-16
>
> Halo: Spartan Strike  Game    343 Industries  2015-04-16
>
> Saint’s Testimony Short Story Frank O'Connor  2015-07-27
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Oasis    Short Story Tobias
>   Buckell   2016-09-20
>
> Second Halo Trilogy   Halo 4  Game    343 Industries  2012-11-06
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: Dominion
>   Splinter  Comic Issue Frank O'Connor  2016-10-25
>
> Halo 4: Sparten Ops   Game    343 Industries  2012-11-06
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: Fireteam Majestic
>   Poker Night   Comic Issue Kody Chamberlain    2016-10-25
>
> Halo: EscalationEscalation, Vol. 1   Graphic Novel    Christopher
>   Schlerf   2014-10-21
>
> Halo: Escalation  Escalation, Vol. 2  Graphic Novel   Brian
>   Reed  2015-04-21
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: Knight Takes
>   Bishop    Comic Issue Tyler Jeffers   2016-10-25
>
> Hunt the Truth    Hunt the Truth (Season 1)   Audio Drama 343
>   Industries    2015-03-22
>
> Halo: Escalation  Escalation, Vol. 3  Graphic Novel   Brian
>   Reed  2015-09-29
>
> Halo: Escalation  Escalation, Vol. 4  Graphic Novel   Duff
>   Boudreu   2016-03-22
>
> Tales from Slipspace  Tales from Slipspace: On the Brink  Comic
>   Issue Duffy Boudreau  2016-10-25
>
> Hunt the Truth    Hunt the Truth (Season 2)   Audio Drama 343
>   Industries    2015-09-22
>
> Envoy Novel   Tobias S. Buckell   2017-04-25
>
> Second Halo Trilogy   Halo 5: Guardians   Game    343
>   Industries    2015-10-27
>
> Halo Wars     Rise of Atriox  Graphic Novel   Alex Irvine, Claire Roe,
>   Cullen Bunn, Jody Houser, John Jackson Miller, Jonathan Wayshak, Josan
>   Gonzalez, Tristan Jones   TBD     Tales from Slipspace    Tales from
>   Slipspace: Undefeated Comic Issue John Jackson Miller 2016-10-25
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: Rossbach’s World Short Story Brian
>   Reed  2016-09-20
>
> Halo: Fractures   Fractures: What Remains Short Story Morgan
>   Lockhart  2016-09-20
>
> Halo Evolutions   Evolutions: The Return  Short Story Kevin
>   Grace 2009-11-24
>
> Halo Wars Halo Wars 2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/235287)

Comment: added the full list as requested